# React, ineffiencies of binding a new function for each event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

My friend and I are having an argument. In the interest of full disclosure, I'm the one who's a big fan of React and its benefits.

In React components, when attaching a DOM event to each element in a list of elements, the traditional pattern is to `bind()` the generic click handler with the values you want to pass along to that function as parameters. As written below:

```
<button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this, buttonIndex)}></button>
```

where `buttonIndex` is some value that changes as the list of buttons is iterated over. This pattern allows `onButtonClick` to be generic, and expect `buttonIndex` as a parameter. Like so:

```
onButtonClick: function(buttonIndex) {
   ... some logic
}
```

My friend argues that this way of doing things is extremely inefficient. This requires that a new function be created and kept in memory to handle each button's event. I agree with his point, but I feel that the React devs wouldn't encourage this pattern [in their docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html), ([at least twice](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)) if the library didn't efficiently handle the events and their handlers.

The pattern he used to avoid this was to use the `data-` attribute and get the value (in this example, `buttonIndex`) off the DOM element itself:

```
<button data-buttonIndex={buttonIndex} onClick={this.onButtonClick}></button>
```

...

```
onButtonClick: function() {
   var buttonIndex = $(this).data('buttonIndex');
   ...some logic
}
```

Again, I'm biased cus I'm the React fan. But this feels wrong, for two reasons:

1. Getting values off the DOM to pass data around (as **state**) kinda defeats the purpose of React in a lot of ways, right?
2. `data-` attributes are extremely ambiguous in my opinion. They can be set from several different places (HTML, JS, PHP, etc.). And they don't suggest any implicit purpose. That "data" could be used anywhere, (JS, CSS, etc.)

Does React do some special magic to be efficent with its DOM events? And if not, is there an alternative pattern that doesn't use the `data-` attribute and is more explicit about its use?

Comment: I'd be curious to hear comments on this. My take: "Extremely" inefficient? How many buttons do you have? `data-` attributes "ambiguous"? Their implicit purpose is... to pass data. Yes, data *can* be used anywhere, which doesn't strike me as inherently bad, since you might *want* to use it from somewhere else. `bind` creates a new function; there's nothing React can do about that, no matter how they handle it, unless they wrote their own bind.

Comment: It's a tradeoff between memory and ease of use.

Comment: As a side point, with ES6, you can now avoid the nasty `bind` and use arrow functions instead: `<button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick(buttonIndex)}></button>`

Comment: @DaveNewton These are buttons in each row of a table, the table could be hundreds of rows long.

Comment: Is your friend certain that `bind` causes the entire function to be duplicated in memory? I would think JavaScript implementors would be smart enough to store the bound function as a reference to the original function along with the bound `this` object and arguments. I can't think of a reason the function itself would be duplicated, but I'd love to hear your friend's reasoning to the contrary.

Comment: @Jordan even if it's not much - it's still needed to be allocated and released during GC cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, but... memoize!

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    this.getClickHandler = _.memoize(this.getClickHandler);
  }

  getClickHandler(index){
    return (event) => {
      doSomething();
    };
  }

  render(){
    // ...
       <button onClick={this.getClickHandler(index)}>Click me</button>
    // ...
  }
}
```

This way you avoid creating a new function, avoid data-attributes, and avoid the performance cost of looking up anything in the dom.

---

I don't think I've ever profiled and found creating functions in render to be an issue. This is definitely something you should optimize only when the numbers tell you to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think in general binding functions directly in `render` is the idiomatic way because they do it in the docs as you pointed out and in our experience has not been significantly less performant. However, there are cases you don't want to rebind the function on every render, for example if you're comparing props in `shouldComponentUpdate` (like with `PureRenderMixin`). To do something very similar as your friend suggests but without looking at the DOM with jQuery (and I believe is a common pattern) you can pass the index as a prop.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return [...some array].map((item, index) => {
      return <Child item={item} index={index} />;
    });
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClickButton = this.handleClickButton.bind(this);
  }

  handleClickButton() {
    // use this.props.index here
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClickButton}></button>;
  }
}
```

Note when using ES6 classes you need to bind to `this` manually in constructor since you're accessing `this.props`. You don't need to if you're using `React.createClass`. [More about ES6 classes in React docs here.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes)