# How to pass the value to function on react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use the same construction `onPress={this.onSave}`
But I don't know how to pass value to function `onSave`.

Comment: You can do it the same way you do it without react or react-native. However, if that component is rerendered a lot, you should create a new component which gets passed the callback and the value to pass to it, so that you don't have to create a new function in each render. I suggest to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366248/react-ineffiencies-of-binding-a-new-function-for-each-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onPress={ () => this.onSave(value) }
```

Comment: I like this solution more, however it's not widely supported in browsers as of now. More info [on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: You are right, but when using React Native, the code is compiled with babel and ES6 works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
onPress={ this.onSave.bind(this, 10) }
```